# About sigprocmask(), SIG_BLOCK and SIG_SETMASK

Tags: c, unix, signals

In the chapter 10 Signals of the APUE.

I have some questions about `sigprocmask()`, `SIG_BLOCK` and `SIG_SETMASK`.

1. The books says "we saved the old mask when we blocked the signal". My understanding is that:

We declare a `newmask` of type `sigset_t`, then `sigempty(&newmask)` means to initalize the newmask so that all signals pointed by `newmask` are excluded, finally add `SIGQUIT` to the `newmask` set.

But I'm not sure what the following means. Is it to `SIG_BLOCK` the the signals pointed by `newmask` and `sigprocmask()` them to the `oldmask`?

`sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask)`

2. "To unblock the signal, we did a `SIG_SETMASK` of the old mask.

The `oldmask` is a `sigset_t` containing `SIGQUIT`, how can this unblock the signal(`SIGQUIT`)?

`sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL)`

Here is the whole code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sig_quit(int signo) {
    printf("caught SIGQUIT\n");
    if (signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("can't reset SIGQUIT\n");
}

int main() {
    sigset_t newmask, oldmask, pendmask;

    if (signal(SIGQUIT, sig_quit) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("can't catch SIGQUIT\n");

    /* Block SIGQUIT and save current signal mask. */
    sigemptyset(&newmask);
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGQUIT);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
       printf("SIG_BLOCK error");
    sleep(5);   /* SIGQUIT here will remain pending */
    if (sigpending(&pendmask) < 0)
       printf("sigpending error");
    if (sigismember(&pendmask, SIGQUIT))
       printf("\nSIGQUIT pending\n");

    /* Restore signal mask which unblocks SIGQUIT. */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
       printf("SIG_SETMASK error");
    printf("SIGQUIT unblocked\n");
    sleep(5);   /* SIGQUIT here will terminate with core file */

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We declare a newmask of type sigset_t, then sigempty(&newmask) means to initalize the newmask so that all signals pointed by newmask are excluded, finally add SIGQUIT to the newmask set.

Not exactly. `sigemptyset()` excludes *all* the signals from `newmask` (i.e. it's an *empty* signal set).

> But I'm not sure what the following means. Is it to SIG_BLOCK the the signals pointed by newmask and sigprocmask() them to the oldmask?

`sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask)` sets the new signal mask using `newmask` (i.e. if successful, only `SIGQUIT` is blocked) and returns the *old* signal mask in `oldmask`.

> The oldmask is a sigset_t containing SIGQUIT, how can this unblock the signal(SIGQUIT)?

That's not true. The *old* signal mask was the ones *before* `SIGQUIT` was blocked, which was returned by `sigprocmask()` when you blocked `SIGQUIT` and stored in `oldmask`. So, `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL)` restores the old signal mask (whatever the signal mask *before* the call to `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask)`).

Comment: As for the `sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask)`, the first two parameters do one thing, while the last parameter do another thing (i.e., just save the original set)? Is this correct? So that's why we need a `pendmask` in the code (can we also use `newmask`, too?)

Comment: "[...]Is this correct?" Yes. `pendmask` is to store the list of signal *pending* (while they have been blocked). You can re-use `newmask` because it's not needed after successful `sigprocmask()` call by emptying it. But it's better to use a different variable for clarity.